# Spring REST repository not exposed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-rest

It is strange but when I have in *Spring Boot* the following *Spring Data Rest* in  config

```
spring:
  data:
    rest:
      default-media-type: application/json
      detection-strategy: annotated
```

and class

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface RestRestaurantRepo extends CrudRepository<Restaurant, Long> {

}
```

It is not exposed. However when I change it to any config where I leave out of the config props like

```
spring:
  data:
    rest:
      detection-strategy: annotated
```

or:

```
spring:
  data:
    rest:
      default-media-type: application/json
```

it works. What can be done about this ?

Answer (score 0):

It is working perfectly fine for me. Do recheck. By default the mediatype is `application/hal+json`. But when you override it from application.properties, it is changed to `application/json`. But the Rest endpoints work perfectlyy fine. It is working even with or without detection-strategy. I am using spring-data-rest 2.6.1